# elfinder выдаёт Invalid backend configuration. Readable volumes not available

Tags: php, laravel

Пытаюсь установить elfinder

установку производил как указано здесь

```
https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-elfinder
```

мой файл config/elfinder.php имеет следующую структуру

```
https://ideone.com/uVpYtn
```

Подскажите в какую строну копать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

нужно было в public положить папку files,или изменить config/elfinder 'dir' => ['название папки в public']